# SpringBootTest: Unable to find table in h2 database

Tags: spring-boot, h2, junit5

I am unit testing a JPA repository with h2 database.

I have placed following annotations on my unit test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

In test, I just call default save method on JPA repository.

Entity is defined with annotations as:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "coverage")
```

And in src/test/resources, I have defined application.properties with details:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.h2geodb.GeoDBDialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

I expect SpringBootTest to read my entity class and create the table in h2 database. But I get error as:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "coverage" does not exist
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're missing @DataJpaTest annotation on the test class

Comment: Adding that causes error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.here.had.webapps.repository.CoverageRepositoryTest]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper)]

Comment: Try remove @SpringBootTest and then should work. I assume you want to make an integration test for a repository. Am I right?
EDIT: Could you confirm if is working now?

Comment: yes, basically its an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to include the H2 database dependency in the `test` scope.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

As long as you use Spring Boot, the framwork automatically detects this dependency in the `test` scope on the classpath and starts the databse for the testing phase with default  settings (matching the same you provided) and no additional configuration required.

I suppose you use jUnit 5, therefore use these annotations for the test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyTest() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you do the integration test you need to load the database configurations in context. hope these annotations will work for your case

```
@DataJpaTest // required
@ActiveProfiles("test") //optional: setting the profile you want to test
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DatabaseConfig.class}) // load the configurations
```

Reference link :

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing
- https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-data-jpa-test/
- https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles